# Android Access Local File From WebView Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, webview

I am looking for an elegant way to access local files (either on phone memory or SD Card) on an Android device from JavaScript running in WebView on an Android device.

I am loading said WebView with a html page from the device located in the assets folder.  Along these lines, I believe I can access any file in this assets folder from the Javascript, but can't load anything from SD card or phone memory.  I am aware of the addJavaScriptInterface, but I am specifically trying to load images, so using this method would require some tweaking to pass a B64 encoded image.

I am new to Android development, and want to make sure I am not missing something obvious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement a ContentProvider to map local files to uris.

Comment: The web link mentioned is broken. That's why it's always a good idea to provide an answer inline.

Answer (score 1):

[Android tip #1 ContentProvider , Accessing local file system from WebView / showing image in webview using content://](http://www.techjini.com/blog/2009/01/10/android-tip-1-contentprovider-accessing-local-file-system-from-webview-showing-image-in-webview-using-content/)

Comment: That link is broken, but Archive.org has it here: http://web.archive.org/web/20101108043507/http://www.techjini.com/blog/2009/01/10/android-tip-1-contentprovider-accessing-local-file-system-from-webview-showing-image-in-webview-using-content/